# Magento 1.9: Price resetting to 0 when custom option is changed

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Recently I have noticed that when changing the options on a product, the price resets to 0 instead of the price that is set in the backend for the specific option. If you add the product to your cart, the price is correct, it is just on the individual product page that the price is incorrect. I have tried the solution found here: [Magento 1.7.0.1 resets price to 0 when using custom options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296457/magento-1-7-0-1-resets-price-to-0-when-using-custom-options) with no success. I have also disabled all of our modules and reverted back to the base theme with no luck.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be helpful to show the relevant backend code that reproduces the problem here in the question. Also, possibly remove the link to the live site or use something that's more obviously a placeholder - the link to a page that appears to be selling jewelry could get flagged as spam.

Comment: I would love to include the code that is causing the problem, but that is the issue I am having. I do not know where to event start looking for what might be causing this problem. I am assuming that it is a piece of JS somewhere but...